# I want to know default font of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Can you tell me what this font (the default font of intelliJ IDEA) is... ?

[image]

Comment: You can find answer to this question with any search engine and few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling of the answer took me 2 minutes, but I'll extract results for you:

> Default fonts used before 2020.1 version depending on the OS:
>
> ```
>    public final static String FALLBACK_FONT_FAMILY         = "Monospaced";
>    public final static String MAC_OS_DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY   = "Menlo";
>    public final static String LINUX_DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY    = "DejaVu Sans Mono";
>    public final static String WINDOWS_DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY  = "Consolas";
> ```

Current default is [JetBrains Mono](https://adtmag.com/articles/2020/04/15/intellij-idea-update.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20recently%20introduced%20JetBrains%20Mono,developers%20to%20improve%20code%20readability.)

Source: [IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform) | JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007965440-How-to-put-the-editor-appearance-back-to-the-previous-version-?page=1#community_comment_360001564299).